# Retrofit 2 posting image and other data

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hello everyone I want to post image and other data through Retrofit2 please guide me where I am lacking in my code

```
@Multipart
    @POST(HttpConstants.FILEUPLOADJSON1)
    Call<Result>uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,@Query("stdID")int stdID);
```

php part

```
  $stdID=$_POST['stdID'];  
    $file_path = "profile_images/";
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    $actualpath="http://myservices.96.lt/$file_path";
    $sql = "UPDATE testuser SET profile_photo = '".$actualpath."' WHERE user_id = '".$stdID."'";



        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) 
            {
                        $result = array("result" => "success", "value" => $sql);
                       } 
else
{
                     $result = array("result" => "error file transfer");
                 }
        }else{
                     $result = array("result" => "error mysql");
                }



    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Fine! What's the issue?

Comment: i am getting the image in the server but my table is not updating the value where am i lagging ?

Comment: You are trying to send @Query parameter within multipart request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `@Part` instead of `@Query` in Multipart request

In your Retrofit api interface pass your parameter as followws.

```
 @Multipart
        @POST(HttpConstants.FILEUPLOADJSON1)
        Call<Result>uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("stdID") stdID);
```

I hope its work for you

Comment: @PratikVyas check my answer as right if its work for you